# IP address country lookup services

Tags: php, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I have used ipinfodb.com for geolocation in the past, but they have a limit of 2 queries per second and the application I am working on will exceed that limit.

I need an alternative for geolocation that is fast and accurate to the country level. I am open to either a database or a web service and I am willing to pay for it.

A web service seems like it's easiest to integrate, but downloading a database is most likely faster. My concern with downloading a database is it becoming inaccurate over time if it isn't updated regularly. Is this a valid concern?

I've heard mixed reviews about Quova.

Anyone have experience with other geolocation services besides ipinfodb?

Comment: MaxMind is pretty solid, and updated regularly:  http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing

Comment: There's a pecl extension for use with the free maxmind database as well: http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip -- this is definitely the lowest-friction PHP solution to geoip lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://uppit.com/4hyisuepbh60/geoip.sql

There's a DB. DB is taken from: http://code.google.com/p/ci-geoip/ just added country_name column

```
$query = query('SELECT country_code, country_name FROM geoip WHERE ' . ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . ' BETWEEN ipnum_start AND ipnum_end');
```

Comment: When was this database last updated? How concerned should I be about the database getting outdated?

Comment: Just update regularly from the sources shown on the google code page :)